# How to also get the index of a random choice json file list

Tags: python, arrays, json, indexing

I am writing a script for a book randomiser selection and I am wondering how do I also print the index number of the randomised choice that has been taken from a json list.

Below is my function for viewing all the data:

```
def view_data():
with open (filename, "r") as f:
    temp = json.load(f)
    i=0
    for entry in temp:
        name = entry["book"]
        print(f"Index Number {i}")
        print(f"Name of book: {name}")
        print("\n\n")
        i=i+1
```

When I run this it shows:

```
Index Number 0
Name of book: Fruit

Index Number 1
Name of book: Salad

Index Number 2
Name of book: Meat

Index Number 3
Name of book: Vegetables

Index Number 4
Name of book: Dinner
```

However when I call my randomiser function it doesn't show the index also:

```
def random_select():
with open (filename, "r") as f:
    temp = json.load(f)
    data_length = len(temp)-1
    i=0
    book_randomiser = random.choice(temp)
    print(book_randomiser)
```

This function prints the below answer:

```py
{'book': 'Salad'}
```

Is there a way to print the index of the book the randomiser selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```py
import random

temp = [
    {"book": "Fruit"},
    {"book": "Salad"},
    {"book": "Meat"},
    {"book": "Vegetables"},
    {"book": "Dinner"},
]

index, book = random.choice(list(enumerate(temp)))
print(index)
print(book)
```

Prints (for example):

```py
3
{'book': 'Vegetables'}
```